# Logical operators in windows search

Tags: filesystems, search, windows-search

I'm trying to make a search for pdf, docx and doc files between 1 and 16 MB. This is what I'm searching for, are my parenthesis doing the job properly? Is there for me to specify size rather than using the default Windows 7 definition?  could I exclude words in the filename by using a minus sign?  I would normally just solve this with trial and error, but the file system i'm searching is several terabytes large.
`size:large AND (*.pdf OR *.docx OR *.doc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there for me to specify size rather than using the default Windows 7 definition?

You can use the `>` and `<` operators with size, to specify a size in bytes:

> `size:>500` - Finds items with a size greater than 500 bytes.
>
> `size:<500` - Finds items with a size less than 500 bytes.

Source [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can also specify a range of sizes as follows:

```
size:>=1mb <=16mb
```

Source [Learn How to Use Windows 7’s Advanced Search Operators](https://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/)

Comment: The note in the Boolean operators section mentions OR and Not, but doesn't mention "AND".  Are you sure AND is a valid operator?

Comment: @wizlog Oops. You are correct. Answer updated to explain how to specify a renge of sizes.